# Does anyone use Java-config for Spring framework now?

Tags: java, spring

I was going through the Spring [Java Config](http://www.springsource.org/javaconfig) page.

It says

> Though the project should now be considered 'decommissioned', the resources herein will remain indefinitely for posterity's sake:

Does that mean it is obsolete? Does anyone use it in their projects right now ? Does it have any advantage over conventional xml configuration?

Answer (score 10):

While the Spring Java Config *project* has ceased (the webpages remain up just to keep links active) the *results* of that project have been folded into the main Spring project as of Spring 3. Thus you should not use the Java Config project's annotations for new code, but rather instead the standard `@Bean` and `@Configuration` (and `@Value`, etc.) annotations.

So long as you use Spring 3, you can use `@Configuration` and `@Value` in the same project as XML configuration. I am doing this and it works really well for complex configuration problems. (I mostly prefer to use XML configuration still, as that gives better support in SpringSource Tool Suite, but for cases where you need to get the name of a class to instantiate for a bean from a property — hey, it's tricky! — then XML config doesn't cut it.)

Comment: In short: project and code obsolete, but style very much _not_ obsolete. Change some class names and use Spring 3. Works _together_ with XML config.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your link you should switch to @Bean and @Configuration.

We are successfully using the @Configuration annotation. I haven't used @Bean yet.

Answer (score -1):

yes.. I been using it and if you are looking for a good resource on learning how check out..

http://johnathanmarksmith.com/Spring/Java/JavaConfig/Programming/2013/04/25/how-to-use-spring-javaconfig-and-not-xml-files-for-configuation/

This is how I learned it from him